# Why aren't my "<li>"s moving to the top when using margin-top

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem when using the css property `margin-top` on `<li>` elements.

I am trying to have my list align to the *top* of the page but my `li` element isn't moving to the top as it should.

Below is my HTML code:

```
<body>
<div class="main_header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/about">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Order">Order</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Designs">Designs</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</body>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
.main_header li a {
    margin-top: -20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't  specify the a because that applies to the link you are moving the link

Comment: Why are you applying margin-top 20px if you want them to be at the top of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your looking for a inline navigation style `ul` change the css to:

```
.main_header li {
    margin-top: -20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If your looking to move the whole list up try:

```
ul {
    margin-top:-10px;
}
```

If your looking to move just the `li` elements closer to each other try:

```
.main_header li {
    display: block;
}
```

Note - if your looking to have a inline navigation, use the `<nav>` html element instead to reduce styling, as it automatically places the links inline

Comment: Thank you my problem was to use ul instead of li

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
.main_header li a{
   margin-top: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

by

```
.main_header li {
   margin-top: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Output

[image]

**### Check it out.**

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather - you're wanting to do something like this...

**HTML**

```
<div class="main_header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/about">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Order">Order</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Designs">Designs</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main_header {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
.main_header ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main_header li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc; 
}

.main_header li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding:10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

**Codepen**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKxGPY